# Possible faster VBA lookup with wildcards?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, wildcard, vlookup

I need to perform a quite a lot of lookups with wildcards on the worksheet using a macro (mainly lookup for value & returning the value from another column *though with proper adjustment it can be also just looking for a value with wildcard*, and some lookups only as checks if the value exists in the dataset). My data can't be sorted and all the lookups are within a loop A or loops within loop A; wildcards are included mostly for condition "string begins with...". I often have to find a value in one row and find corresponding value in row N rows below or above.

I have a working code, but I wonder if it can be done faster. @response to comment about posting it on Code Review (sorry, I cannot comment yet :)) - preparation the whole code to posting would take a bit too much time for me, confidentiality etc, so I prefer to treat it as a general question to be worked on this example.

Example data (I can add more columns, if I need any helper column):

[Example Data picture at Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUt7s.png)

Assume 100 000 rows (max xPagesCount = 1000, typically around 400; all values for certain xPage is in one block). Due to a lot of possible rows with additional data I can't simply find one value and add numbers to the found row to find the other values by their position.

Example lookups to perform while looping through consecutive xPages (so, for each given xPage):

- value in row just below row with "RESTRICTIONS:" text
- find name (which is always given with height (column C) = 35)
- find RSW number (which can be in several rows depending on page content, but always below name)
- find all rows starting with the same four digits as RSW, in two formats: DDDD.LLL.DD and DDDD.DDDDD.DD (L letter, D digit) (I use internal loop here)
- check if there is a text "MASTER" (or "MASTER " etc.)
- find all values between values "DOCUMENTS:" and "OPTIONS:", which quantity can be from 1 to 50 (I use internal loop here)

I was wondering, **what is the fastest way to do such lookups?**
*What I tried:*

- using a dictionary on all dataset (keys in column A or C with, values
  col.D) but as dictionary can't work on wildcards, I had to add ifs
  for not finding a key to perform additional Application.Match
  lookup... and then realized it mostly worked on these Match lookups
  and not sure I even need a dictionary. I also have duplicate values
  within a page and dictionary was getting only first value, regardless
  their position (for example, several attachments could have value 1).
  The main use remained dict.exists("MASTER") but when I removed
  dictionary and changed it to IsError(Application.Match(...)) the code
  worked slightly faster.
- Application.Match in whole range, typical example: `Application.Match(xPage & "4???.*", sh.Range("A1:A" & LastRow), 0)`
- in few places I use `If xValue Like "????.???.??"  Then` construction
- I have dictionary lookups with ifs redirecting to Application.Match:

```
xValue = dict(xPage & "ATH.416")
If dict(xPage & "ATH.416") = "" Then xValue = Application.Match("ATH.*", Sheets(1).Range("D:D"), 0)
```

*What I consider, but not sure it's worth the effort:*

- altering the code that at the beginning of the iteration I find the first and the last row for xPage, and then each later check is performed in this range

```
xStartPage = sh.Range("D" & Application.Match(xPage, sh.Range("A1:A" & LastRow), 0))
'or, I guess better:
xStartPage = xEndPage + 1

If xPage = xPagesCount Then
    xEndPage = LastRow
Else
    xEndPage = sh.Range("D" & Application.Match(xPage + 1, sh.Range("A1:A" & LastRow), 0) - 1)
End If

xValue = sh.Range("D" & Application.Match("4???.*", sh.Range("D" & xStartPage & ":D" & xEndPage), 0)).Value
```

Comment: Since you are having a working code, it should be posted on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) / [Super User](https://superuser.com/) forum .

Comment: if you don't measure, how will you improve it?